# Chevalley's Theorem: a step in the proof from Vakil's FOAG

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, schemes

I'm trying to solve the following exercises (7.4.M and 7.4.N) from Vakil's FOAG, on the proof of Chevalley's theorem, but I'm not sure if what I've done is correct. I would like to someone to provide feedback on the correctness of my solution, and if it's wrong, how I can solve it with the material developed by Vakil so far in the book.
[image]

Here's my attempt:

$X$ is Noetherian and thus, compact. Pick a finite affine cover of $X$, which I'll denote by $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$. Any subset $Z$, of $X$ is constructible iff each $Z\cap U_i$ is constructible. Since $\pi (Z) = \cup_{i\in I}\pi (Z\cap U_i)$, it suffices to prove that each
$\pi (Z\cap U_i)$ is constructible. This lets us assume that $X$ is affine. This proves the latter part of 7.4.N.

Suppose $X = \text{Spec }A$. Since $X$ is Noetherian, we may write $Z$ as the disjoint union of some locally closed subsets, say $Z_j\cap V_j$, where $Z_j$ are closed and $V_j$ are open. Since each $V_j$ is compact, being a subset of a Noetherian space, we may cover each $V_i$ by finitely many affines, and by an argument similar to the one in the previous paragraph, we may assume that $V_j$ itself is affine. Now, $Z_j = \text{Spec } A/I$, for some ideal $I$ of $A$. Thus, $Z_j\cap V_j$ is actually an open subscheme of $Z_j$. Since it suffices to show that $\pi (Z_j\cap V_j)$ is constructible, and we're taking finite union of these individual "pieces" we've built along the way, it in fact suffices to show that the image of a scheme under the given hypotheses is constructible. This finishes the proof of 7.4.M.

To finish the first part of 7.4.N, we break Y up into finitely many affine "pieces" and use a similar argument as before.

One of the reasons I'm a bit unsure whether this proof is true is the existence of solutions at [chevalleys theorem reduces to showing image of whole scheme is constructible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3352533/chevalleys-theorem-reduces-to-showing-image-of-whole-scheme-is-constructible) and [Hartshorne Exercise II. 3.19 (a)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259609/hartshorne-exercise-ii-3-19-a), both of which seem to use stuff which Vakil hasn't covered yet. For instance, he's not done closed subschemes yet, but I guess we may work in a closed subset of an affine scheme, which is something that would like $\text{Spec }A/I$ above. Further, I seem to require the latter part of 7.4.N for 7.4.M.

I would be very grateful is someone could point out where I've gone wrong, or assure me that what I've done is right.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7.4.M. : Let $Z$ be a constructible subset of $X$ and $\pi: X\to Y$.

Assume that image of any finite type morphism of noetheian schemes in constructibe. Now $Z$ is a disjoint union of $Z_i$ where each $Z_i$ is a locally closed subset of $X$. So to show $\pi(Z)$ is constructible, it suffices to show each  $\pi(Z_i)$ is constructible. Now $Z_i=U_i\cap F_i$ where $U_i$ is an open subset and $F_i$ is a closed subset of $X$. Put the reduced induced structure on $F_i$, that induces a scheme structure on the open subset $Z_i=U_i\cap F_i\subset F_i$. Now consider the map $$\phi|_{Z_i}:Z_i\to Y $$ given by the restriciton of the map $$\phi: F_i\to X\to Y.$$

Now by our assumption image of $\phi|_{Z_i}=\pi(Z_i)$ is constructible. So this proves. 7.4.M.

7.4.N. : (First reduction) Now we want to reduce to the case $Y$ is affine. We have $\pi:X\to Y$. Now cover $Y$ by affine open subsets $Spec ~A$'s. Now $$\pi(X)=\bigcup_i \pi( \pi^{-1}(Spec~ A_i)).$$

So it suffices to show image of $\pi: \pi^{-1}(Spec~ A_i)\to Spec ~ A_i$ is constructible.

So we have reduced to the case where $Y$ is affine.

(second reduction):
Now we want to reduce to the case $X$ is affine. We have $\pi:X\to Y$ with $Y$ affine.

Again cover $X$ be affine open $Spec ~B$'s. Now $$\pi(X)=\bigcup_i\pi( Spec~B_i).$$ So it suffices to consider $X$ affine.

I hope this clears up the sequence of reductions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have just one question though: in 7.4.M, we "Put the reduced induced structure on $F_i$", is this more or less what I outlined in the third paragraph of my post? (that is, the second paragraph of my attempted solution)

Comment: @user940160 Yes. More precisely given a closed subset $T$ of a scheme $X$, there is a unique scheme structure on $T$ such that $T$ is a closed subscheme of $X$ and further the scheme $T$ is reduced. See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01J3.