# Proof of Chevalley's theorem in Milne's book

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, dominant-morphisms

I'm facing some difficulties into understanding the proof of the famous "Chevalley Theorem" in Milne's "Algebraic Geometry" (page 196)

> A regular morphism $\varphi:W\to V$ between algebraic varieties sends constructible sets to constructible sets. In particular, if $U$ is a nonempty open subset of $W$, then $\varphi(U)$ contains a nonempty open subset of its closure in $V$.

**EDIT:** Thanks to KReiser and Aphelli, now my only doubt is the third and last one, so there's no need to address the first two doubts.

**My attempt of grasping the proof**

The author first proves the "In particular" part of the statement and says that

*"by considering suitable open affine coverings of $W$ and $V$, we see that it suffices to prove this in the case that both $V$ and $W$ are affine varieties".*

***I think that I need more detail on this step. Let $\mathcal{U}=\{U_i\}$ be an affine covering of $W$. Clearly by choosing wisely the covering I can suppose that $f(U_i)$ is contained in an affine open set $\widetilde{U}_i$. Let's suppose that I already proved the "in particular" part of the statement for affine varieties so that $\varphi:U_i\to \widetilde{U}_i$ satisfies the "in particular" property. This means that $\varphi(U\cap U_i)$ contains an open subset $A_i$ of $\overline{\varphi(U\cap U_i)}\cap \widetilde{U}_i$ (I use the overline just for the closure in $V$ and in this case we are talking about the closure in $\widetilde{U}_i$). Clearly $A_i$ can be written as $\widetilde{A}_i\cap \overline{\varphi(U\cap U_i)}\cap \widetilde{U}_i$ where $\widetilde{A}_i$ is an open subset of $V$. So:***

$$\varphi(U)=\bigcup_i \varphi(U\cap U_i)\supseteq \bigcup_i A_i \supseteq \left(\bigcup_i \overline{\varphi(U\cap U_i)}\right)\cap \bigcap_i \widetilde{A}_i\cap\widetilde{U}_i=\overline{\varphi(U)}\cap \bigcap_i \widetilde{A}_i\cap\widetilde{U}_i $$

***and this would conclude the problem if I knew that $\bigcap_i \widetilde{A}_i \cap \widetilde{U}_i\neq \varnothing$. Am I overcomplicating this step? I don't see a simple way to do this.***

Moving along with the proof, the author says that we can also suppose $W$ to be irreducible because if $W_1,...,W_r$ are its irreducible components, then
$$\varphi(U)=\bigcup_j \varphi(U\cap W_j)$$
so I think that using a reasoning similar to the one of the previous step we can limit ourselves to the case $W$ irreducible (but I still don't know how to complete properly this reasoning).

Now the author says that we can also suppose $V$ to be irreducible and I'm not really convinced by the motivation:

*"We can restrict the codomain $V$ to the closure of the image."*

***We are basically saying that if $\varphi(U)$ contains a nonempty subset of $\overline{\varphi(U)}\cap \overline{\varphi(W)} $ then it contains a nonempty subset of $\overline{\varphi(U)}$ and I don't understand why.***

Moving along with the proof. Since the map $\varphi:W\to \overline{\varphi(W)}$ is dominant the image contains a dense open subset of the codomain, so the "in particular" part is proved.

Now we have to prove that th image of a constructible set is constructible. I understand that we can suppose $W$ and $C$ to be irreducible (clearly this implies that $\overline{C}$ is a closed subvariety of $W$). The theorem is now proven by induction on $\dim(W)$. The case $\dim(W)=0$ is trivial.

The inductive step is trivial if $\overline{C}\neq W$ because then  $\dim(\overline{C})<\dim(W)$ (because of the irreducibility assumptions) and I can apply the inductive hyphothesis to $\varphi|_{\overline{C}}$ (clearly $C$ is also constructible in $\overline{C}$).

The hard case if $\overline{C}=W$. In this case $\overline{C}$ contains a nonempty open subset $O$ of $W$. Now the author comes to another tricky point

*"The case just proved shows that $\varphi(C)$ contains a nonempty subset $U$ of its closure (in $V$)"*

***I've tried to understand this part with the following reasoning. By a precedent proposition I know that $C$ contains a nonempty open subset $\widetilde{O}$ of $\overline{C}$. Let $O\cap \widetilde{O}$. Clearly $\varphi(C)\supseteq \varphi(O\cap \widetilde{O})$ and by the "in particular" part of the proposition $\varphi(U)$ contains a nonempty open subset $U$ of the closure $\overline{\varphi(O\cap \widetilde{O})}$. So $\varphi(C)$ contains  $U$ but this doesn't prove anything because I don't know if $U$ is open in $\overline{\varphi(C)}$.***

Moving along with the proof, we can write

$$\varphi(C)=U\cup \varphi(C\cap \varphi^{-1}(\overline{\varphi(C)}-U))$$

Since $\varphi$ is continous $\varphi^{-1}(\overline{\varphi(C)}-U)$ is closed and it's a proper closed set because $\overline{C}=W$ and I can suppose $\varphi$ to be dominant (by simply restricting its codomain to the closure of the image). Clearly $C\cap \varphi^{-1}(\overline{\varphi(C)}-U)$ is constructible in $\varphi^{-1}(\overline{\varphi(C)}-U)$ so by inductive hyphothesis $\varphi(C\cap \varphi^{-1}(\overline{\varphi(C)}-U))$ is constructible in $V$ and this clearly implies that $\varphi(C)$ is constructible.

I'd be grateful if you could help me with the tricky steps. Even if you know how to help me just on some steps I'd be happy.

Comment: This is a lot of questions all in one post, some (many?) of which already have answers on MSE (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217182/chevalleys-theorem-a-step-in-the-proof-from-vakils-foag?rq=1) for the affine reduction, for instance). You seem very stuck on the "in particular" text - I'd ignore that while trying to read the proof, it's just meant as a nice consequence of the theorem.

Comment: The answer you linked is written in the language of schemes and I don't know schemes.

Comment: I don’t think you need schemes to read the linked answer. You can just pretend they’re varieties.

Comment: @Aphelli Okay I understand how this "affine reduction" works for proving that the image of a constructible set is still constructible. But I don't understand how the "in particular" part of the statement works. The first comment says that it's just a nice consequence of the main theorem but I don't see how. An open subset $U$ is constructible so by the main theorem $\varphi(U)$ is still constructible. If $\varphi(U)$ is irreducible then the it contains a nonempty subset of its closure by a previous proposition, but what if it's not irreducible?

Comment: So what you’re asking is: if $T \subset V$ is constructible, why does it contain an open subset of its closure?  Hint: you can assume that $T$ is dense, then consider the irreducible components of $Z$…

Comment: @Aphelli Thank you very much :), now I see it. Now my only doubt is the third (and last one) in the question (it seems to be that it's not addressed in the post linked by KReiser).

Comment: @Aphelli I understand that since we've reduced to the dominant case clearly since $\overline{C}=W$ we have that $\varphi(\overline{C})$ contains an dense open subset of its closure ( for the properties of dominant map between affine varieties). But I can't see why $\varphi(C)$ contains a nonempty open subset.

Comment: The proof has been rewritten in the latest version of Milne's notes.